# How do I put `proj/.dart_tool` in a `/tmp` folder, or otherwise signal to `rsync` to ignore that directory?

Tags: flutter, dart, rsync

I like to `rsync` source files to a removable flash disk, as a macOS backup of last resort.

But the `rsync` gets slowed down considerably by the many cached files, such as:

```
~/proj/.dart_tool/chrome-device/Default/Cache/3027979cf48c4ed1_0
```

which do not need to be backed up at all.

With `git` it's easy enough to add the line

```
.dart_tool/
```

to `~/proj/.gitignore`.

How do I signal to `rsync` to ignore `.dart_tool`, along with all files and directories in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `rsync`'s `--exclude` flag and target the files you want with a glob.

In your case it would be something like this:

```
rsync --exclude '.dart_tool/chrome-device/Default/Cache/**/*' . /mounted/drive
```